# How to fit a statistical distribution data to a mixure of normal and lognormal distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, fitting, finite-mixture-model

I have a data set that is a mixture of one normal and one lognormal distribution. How can I fit the data to get the fit parameters? Can somebody help me with this.

Comment: In what sense do you know this or have grounds for saying it?

Comment: If you're new to Gaussian Mixture models (GMM), Nathan Kutz explains them well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5amKlNtIoT0